# How do I evaluate $\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_C \frac{e^{zt}}{(z^2 + 1)^2} \,dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

How do I evaluate this integral when t > 0 and C is the Circle $\mid z \mid$ = 3 using Cauchy's Integral Formula

Comment: @Chappers editted, sorry

Comment: your integral is a laplace inversion expression so look into this page http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf

Comment: The function will have two poles within the circle. You could compute the residues there.

Comment: @JoseGarcia But im supposed to solve it using Cauchy's, no? I guess im still stuck

Comment: yes you need to exand $ \frac{1}{(z^2+1)^{2}} $ into partial fractions

Comment: @JoseGarcia: it may look like a Laplace inversion - and it may return the same answer as a Laplace inversion in this case - but the integral is NOT an inverse Laplace transform.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform#Mellin.27s_inverse_formula

Comment: @RonGordon Then how should I proceed, if you can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To evaluate the integral $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_C \frac{e^{zt}}{(z^2 + 1)^2} \,dz$ we see $(z^2+1)^2=(z+i)^2(z-i)^2$. The Cauchy Integral formula says
$$f'(z_0)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z-z_0|=\rho}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}\,dz$$
Since $C$ is the circle $|z|=3$ oriented counter-clockwise, we divide it to $C_1: |z-i|=\frac12$ and $C_2: |z+i|=\frac12$ both oriented counter-clockwise. So here $z_0=\pm i$ and
\begin{eqnarray}
\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{e^{zt}}{(z^2 + 1)^2}\,dz
  &=& \dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C_1} \frac{\frac{e^{zt}}{(z+i)^2}}{(z-i)^2}\,dz + \dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C_2}\frac{\frac{e^{zt}}{(z-i)^2}}{(z+i)^2}\,dz\\
  &=& \left(\frac{e^{zt}}{(z+i)^2}\right)'\Big|_{z=i} + \left(\frac{e^{zt}}{(z-i)^2}\right)'\Big|_{z=-i}\\
  &=& \frac{e^{+it}(2it-2)}{-8i} + \frac{e^{-it}(-2it-2)}{8i}\\
  &=& \color{blue}{\dfrac{\sin t-t\cos t}{2}}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I appreciate your answer but the book says the answer is $\frac{1}{2} (sin (t) - t cos(t))$
Any clue why it might difer?

Comment: @Forzzark Sorry! It was my wrong in simplification was edited.